# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having issues with a relationship between 2 entities;

My classes are as follows;

```
public class Cis 
{
     [Key]
     public int CisId { get; set; }
     public int ProjectId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("ProjectId")] 
     public virtual ICollection<Overhead> Overheads { get; set; }

}   

public class Overhead 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public SecuredWorkType SecuredWorkType { get; set; }
    public decimal? OverheadRecoveryTotalValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? BudgetedFinancialResultValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? SecuredValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? OverheadRecoveryTotalPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to save a CIS object with multiple overheads on it, I get the following error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Overhead_dbo.Cis_ProjectId". The conflict occurred in database "CisLatest", table "dbo.Cis", column 'CisId'.The statement has been terminated."
```

I cannot use the CisId on the Cis as my foreign key because of design concerns - when I was using the CisId as the foreign key it worked fine.

I have seen similar questions and answers on here, though they show putting the parent entity inside the child? Not sure if this applies in this case

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1. `ProjectId` in both models. 2. what is the real relation here? to make `[ForeignKey("ProjectId")]` working you need to set `[Key]` in `Overhead`

Comment: The application structure is; One project, which has many Cis's and has many overheads. Now that I'm thinking about it, with this in mind there is no need to have a direct relationship between CIS and overhead, being that the overhead is per project and not Cis, this might be where I'm getting confused.

Comment: Looks like you need to rethink your data structure. At his point, I think, you need: `Project`,`Cis`,`Overhead`,`Project_Cis`,`Project_Overhead`. Suddenly, looks like you can build your EDM

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public class Cis 
{
    [Key]
    public int CisId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")] //here
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Overhead> Overheads { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no good I'm afraid - got this error when I tried the migration with the Foreign key attribute above projectId in the Cis class ; "The property 'ProjectId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type."